# How to do css position code for div boxs?

Tags: html, css

I have three div boxes

box1 - menu, box3 - info, and box2 - slide box which I want to be back of box1 and box3,   (As the photo shows  http://s16.postimg.org/u9mwuhmcl/111.png)

My attempt:

```css
    .box1 {
      width:980px;
      height:100px;
      background-color:#CCCCCC;
    }
     
    .box2 {
      width:980px;
      height:100px;
      background-color:#000;
      position:relative;
         z-index:1 ;
    }
    
    .box3 {
      width:980px;
      height:100px;
      background-color:#CCCCCC;
     
    }
```

```html
    <div class="box1">Menu</div>
    <div class="box2">Slider</div>
    <div class="box3">Info text</div>
```

Comment: Show some CSS, please

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Answer (score 1):

Here is one options using position relative on the top and bottom boxes.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5w5hub7v/2/)

```css
* {
  color: white;
}
.box1,
.box3 {
  margin: auto;
}
.box2 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
.box1 {
  width: 980px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  position: relative;
  top: 1em;
}
.box3 {
  width: 980px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  position: relative;
  top: -1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">Menu</div>
<div class="box2">Slider</div>
<div class="box3">Info text</div>
```

2nd option with position relative on the second box.

[**JSfiddle Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/5w5hub7v/3/)

```css
* {
  color: white;
}
.box1,
.box3 {
  margin: auto;
}
.box2 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
  top: -1em;
  z-index: -1;
}
.box1 {
  width: 980px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  position: relative;
}
.box3 {
  width: 980px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">Menu</div>
<div class="box2">Slider</div>
<div class="box3">Info text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this-

```css
.box1 {
      width:90%;
      height:100px;
      background-color:#CCCCCC;
      margin:0 auto;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
      bottom: -10px;
    }
     
    .box2 {
      width:100%;
      height:100px;
      background-color:red;
      position:relative;
      z-index:1 ;
      margin:0 auto;
      padding:10px;
    }
    
    .box3 {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    width:90%;
    z-index: 4;
```

```html
<div class="box1">Menu</div>
    <div class="box2">Slider</div>
    <div class="box3">Info text</div>
```

I hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.box1, .box3 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

.box2 {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for box 1 and box 3.
Note: please set top,width,height according to your need.

```
.box1 {
      width:500px;
      height:50px;
      background-color:#CCCCCC;
      position:absolute;
      left:0px;
      right:0px;
      top:0px;
    }

.box3 {
  width:500px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#CCCCCC;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  top:100px;
}
```

For box 3

```
.box3 {
      width:980px;
      height:100px;
      background-color:#CCCCCC;
     margin-top:40px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You better need a wrapper to simply the code.
No need to play with **z-index** in your case because **position: relative;** will give your block priority to the default **position: static;**

```css
.wrapper{
    width: 980px;
}

.box1, .box3 {
    height:100px;
    margin: 0 20px;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    box-sizing: padding-box;
    position: relative;
}

.box2 {
    height:100px;
    margin: -20px 0;
    background-color:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box1">Menu</div>
    <div class="box2">Slider</div>
    <div class="box3">Info text</div>
</div>
```